# Modifying last element of matrix modifies last element of every array in matrix

Tags: python

I tried setting the last element of a 2d matrix in Python3, but it set the last element of each of the last arrays for integers, and just the last element for char. Is it that the array is referenced for primitive data types or is there some reason/reference to why this happens?

With characters:

```
abc = [['a','b','c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
abc[-1]
['g', 'h', 'i']
abc[-1][-1]
'i'
abc[-1][-1] = 'z'
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'z']]
```

With ints:

```
dp = [[0] * 7] * 3
dp
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
dp[-1][-1] = 1
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: The problem is that when you created the list using the multiplication syntax `dp = [[0] * 7] * 3` each element is a reference to the same object. You can test this by checking `dp[ 0 ] is dp[ 1 ]`

Comment: Got it. That seems to be it. Thanks bicarlsen. Just tested: if you use dp = [[0]*3 for i in range(7)], that creates arrays that are not referencing each other.